# How do I allow getting Facebook event invitations from the general public?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-groups, facebook-privacy, facebook-events

I don't see anything in the privacy settings that would prevent people from inviting me to events. Some people say they cannot invite me to events as my name is not populating, even though we are part of the same Facebook Group. Here is the screen shot of the privacy settings.

[image: facebook privacy settings]